# jQuery - insert php variable in .css() function

Tags: php, jquery, css, variables

How can I insert a php var in jQuery? I tried like this but doesn't work:

```
<?php 
     list($width,$height)=getimagesize($row['photo1']);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#photo1").css({'width': '500', 'position': 'relative', 'top': 'calc((100% - <?php echo $height ?> ) / 2 )'});
    });
</script>
     <img id="photo1" src="<?php echo $row['photo1'] ?>" />
```

P.s.: the image is in a div which has 500 x 500 pixels. I want to position the image equidistant from top and bottom.

Comment: Define doesn't work. What's the source code output in the browser?...

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What does `'calc((100% - <?php echo $height ?> ) / 2 )'` evaluate to?

Comment: Try moving the `<script>...</script>` AFTER the `<img....` you are trying to get it to manipulate

Comment: @RiggsFolly that shouldn't make a difference, since it is running on `$(document).ready`

Comment: @JacobGray Good point I had not noticed that

Comment: On inspect element? or "view page source" this is the output code:                 <div class="image-div"><img id="photo1" src="image.jpg" style="width: 500px; position: relative;"></div>

Comment: What do you get when you "View Source"? When you "View Source", you should be able to see the proper value in that location, or you may see some flavor of error.

Comment: What is the value of `$height`? Are you sure?  Can you prove it?

Comment: I'm sure that list($width, $height) return the height and width of the image. I checked it

Comment: But what does it return exactly, does it have a unit included? Non-zero values without units generally don't mean much in css.

Comment: Is `list($width,$height)=getimagesize($row['photo1']);` syntactically correct?

Comment: You could try adding `px` to the width and height value i.e. `width:750px; height:321px` to make the css valid @jeroen basically hit it,

Comment: If I type 'echo $width' or 'echo $height', it returns the width and height of image. In my case is 750 and 321

Comment: There you go, see my previous comment...

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't need `px` if value is a number...but appears to be string. jQuery will add `px` to numeric values

Comment: I know why didn't work. I forgot to put 'px' after 'calc((100% - <?php echo $height ?>'

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by CSS alone. No need for javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/volzy/5sh5k87w/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: To those downvoting: This answer doesn't solve the php issue, but it actually DOES solve the issue that the OP is asking!

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your original question:

> How can I insert a php var in jQuery? I tried like this but doesn't work:

Check the source code outputted to the browser, I'm 99% sure it worked fine. but getimagesize function doesn't output px, its designed to be placed in the HTML attribute for height/ width, which doesn't require a measurement. So your CSS calc is getting (100% - 500) and will fail.

Edited stupid math @jeroen